# why static methods will not throw NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#-3.0

Why static methods will not throw NullReferenceException? or will it throw NullReferenceException? If it will not throw the error, can anyone explain why with relevant example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Static methods don't relate to an instance of the type, so there's no reference to potentially be null.

Of course, if the *body* of a static method does something which will normally throw an exception, it will be propagated as usual:

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        GoBang();
    }

    static void GoBang()
    {
        string s = null;
        int y = s.Length; // Bang! NullReferenceException
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `SomeClass o = null; o.StaticMethod();` in languages that allow you to call static methods through an instance?

Comment: @Bart: Such languages ought to be shot :( In that case (at least for Java) the static method is determined at compile-time, and the execution-time value is ignored... it's never *actually* dereferenced, so there's no exception.

Answer (score 2):

Static method are called with class which is never `null`. Instance methods are called with instance which can be `null` as the programmer did not do `new` on it.

Answer (score 0):

The CLR considers any type to be unstable if it throws an unhandled exception (of any kind) in a type constructor. Attempting to access any member of the unstable type will cause a TypeInitializationException to be thrown.

So, NullReferenceException will be thrown but is marshalled into the TypeInitializationException by the runtime.